# Регистрация аккаунта разработчика Google Play в Казахстане

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать все нюансы при созданий аккаунтов google и admob.
 
1) Что нужно для регистраций аккаунтов?
 
2) Есть ли какие-нибудь ограничений для Казахстана?
 
3) Обязательно ли иметь долларовый счет?
4) Кроме admob-а какие есть виды монетизаций?<sup>(кроме внутри-игровых покупок и платных приложений)</sup>
 
Заранее спасибо и с наступающим!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play для разработчиков из Казахстана доступен уже 3 года как:

1. Единоразовый вступительный взнос $25 для регистрации девелопером
2. Долларовый счет не нужен, важно чтобы банк/счет имел SWIFT/IBAN привязку, чтобы можно было получать забугорные тугрики на счет
3. В остальном все стандартно - все как и у всех